# How Many Sets of 5 Can You Make From 22 Elements?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I know you can just say $\large\frac{22!}{(22!-5!)5!}$. My question is deeper than this, however. What if the set of 5 cannot be used again?

For instance, I have 22 coloured balls, my first set of 5 balls is as follows:-

Blue
Red
Green
Yellow
White

Also, I can never have a different combination of the same 5 balls, for instance the following could not be counted either:-

Red
Blue
Green
Yellow
White

I can't use the same set again, but I can replace one of the elements, like so:-

Blue
Red
Green
Purple
White

How many different combinations of 5 can I make from my 22 balls? Is there a formula for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "using the same set again"? No set of $5$ balls is counted twice in $$\binom{22}{5}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just $\dbinom{22}{5} = \dfrac{22!}{5!(22-5)!}$. It appears you have gotten the formula wrong. Also, the above formula does not count repeats as you are suggesting it does.

Comment: No way, there are definitely not 26,334 combinations of 22 balls

Comment: There sure are!

Comment: It seems like there is a permutation / combination issue going on here. I can pick 5 balls random from 22 in $22*21*20*19*18$ ways if all balls are different. Is that the question here??

Comment: Wow, this is interesting! Just to clarify though, this formula holds even if the same 5 balls can never be counted more than once? So if I had BRGYW, there could never be a WYGRB?

Comment: Correct.  You are coloring the balls with $22$ different colors.  This merely means that the balls are disntinguishable.  Just as the integers $1, 2, \dots, 22$ are disntinguishable.  No difference.  If BRGYW is chosen, it is counted once as the set $\{B,R,G,Y,W\}$.  The $5!$ permutations of this set are accounted for by the $5!$ that appears in the denominator of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!